# How to provide different values for multiple servers for same variable

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook that installs IIS, configures apppools, websites and deploys the application. Now i have got a unique requirement. Unique in the sense,i am still clueless on how to do it :-). The requirement is to set the recycle team at 15 mins apart among the cluster of 4 servers. i.e. the 1st server will have recycle time as 10:00 PM, 2nd at 10:15 PM and so on ...

Any pointers on how to achieve it ...

I have already setup app pool with below settings

```
- name: Setup TestWorkerApi Apppool in IIS
  win_iis_webapppool:
   name: TestWorkerApi
   state: started
   attributes:
     managedPipelineMode: Integrated
     startMode: AlwaysRunning
     processModel.identityType: SpecificUser
     processModel.userName: '{{ Domain }}\{{ Test_In_User }}'
     processModel.password: "{{ Test_In_Pwd }}"
     managedRuntimeVersion: v4.0
     processModel.idleTimeout: 0
     processModel.idleTimeoutAction: Suspend
     recycling.periodicRestart.schedule: ["22:00:00"]
     autoStart: yes
   register: apppool_output-TestWorkerApi
  tags:
     - TestApp
```

I am looking for app pool recycle time as 10:00 PM on 1st server, 10:15 PM on 2nd server, 10:30 PM on 3rd server etc ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ansible allows you to set host-specific variables...

(a) in your inventory, and
(b) in variables files inside your `host_vars` directory.

In either case, you could set a `recycle_time` variable for each host with your desired value.  For example, using the legacy inventory format, that might look like:

```
server1 recycle_time=22:00:00
server2 recycle_time=22:15:00
server3 recycle_time=22:30:00
server4 recycle_time=22:45:00
```

Or using the YAML inventory format:

```
all:
  hosts:
    server1:
      recycle_time: "22:00:00"
    server2:
      recycle_time: "22:15:00"
    server3:
      recycle_time: "22:30:00"
    server4:
      recycle_time: "22:45:00"
```

Or using the `host_vars` directory you would create `host_vars/server1.yml` with the content:

```
recycle_time: "22:00:00"
```

...and similarly for the other servers.

In any case, you would then reference that `recycle_time` variable in your playbook:

```
- name: Setup TestWorkerApi Apppool in IIS
  win_iis_webapppool:
   name: TestWorkerApi
   state: started
   attributes:
     managedPipelineMode: Integrated
     startMode: AlwaysRunning
     processModel.identityType: SpecificUser
     processModel.userName: '{{ Domain }}\{{ Test_In_User }}'
     processModel.password: "{{ Test_In_Pwd }}"
     managedRuntimeVersion: v4.0
     processModel.idleTimeout: 0
     processModel.idleTimeoutAction: Suspend
     recycling.periodicRestart.schedule: [{{ recycle_time }}]
     autoStart: yes
   register: apppool_output-TestWorkerApi
  tags:
     - TestApp
```

You can read more in the "[Variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html)" section of the Ansible documentation.

Comment: Thanks Larsks, thanks for the info. i would go with everything contained under a playbook, so 2nd option looks positive for me. I had other scenarios for which your 2nd solution gave me some pointers and looks apt. Thanks again.